# Taxonomy from URL

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

I want to show a views-block on a taxonomy page.

There are two taxonomy vocabularies.

Collections: bronze, silver, gold & Sizes: small, medium, large

So I have url's like this:
collections/bronze/small

So what I want to do: show articles that have a taxonomy term "collection" set to "bronze" and size set to "small".

I found similar problems, but I can't get it to work :(

[Same issue](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13594/how-do-i-get-a-block-to-use-a-url-to-configure-a-contextual-filter), but didn't work out for me:

Edit: Hmm, it works when I enter "bronze" into "Preview with contextual filters:", but when I try it on the taxonomy page nothing is shown. My path looks like this:
http://localhost/drupalwebsite/?q=collections/bronze

Overview of my view settings:

Fields:
Title
CK field: Image

Contextual filter:
Collections taxonomy term

When value NOT available:
Provide default value -> Raw value from URL -> 2th component.

When value IS available:
Specify validation criteria -> Validator: Taxonomy -> Type: Term name conv. to ID -> Transform dashes to spaces

The taxonomy "sizes" isn't included yet in my view!

Comment: Enable the "taxonomy term" view, it's disabled by default. Then configure the 2 contextual filters.

Comment: Please tell us what filters, fields and context filters (and settings) you have.

Comment: Edited my previous post, there's an overview of my view now. 

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Enabling the "taxonomy term" view is not such a bad idea... Is there an easy way to show the taxonomy terms: "sizes" if I go to the "collection" taxonomy page? Because they are divided in 3 sizes... Maybe I can make children in the "collection" taxonomy... Gold, with children Small, Medium and Large... Instead of using two taxonomy vocabularies. So I want to show the children of the taxonomy term if there are children. Otherwise I want to show the products.

Comment: Hmm, the "taxonomy term" view doesn't show the "body / description (I use a dutch version so I don't know how it is called in english)" of the term on the page like the regular taxonomy pages does... THIS CAN BE EASILY SOLVED: http://www.pridedesign.ie/content/drupal-taxonomy-description-view

Comment: If you use the method I found above, use "taxonomy_term_load" instead of "taxonomy_get_term" in Drupal 7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enabling the "taxonomy term" view and changing the settings is a way to solve this problem.

If you want to show the "taxonomy description" on your view you can use this method:
http://www.pridedesign.ie/content/drupal-taxonomy-description-view

In Drupal 7 use the taxonomy_term_load() function instead of the taxonomy_get_term() function.