# How to filter views rows whose nid is less than nid provided by url?

Tags: views

Drupal 7. In a node/edit form panel I have added a view that returns nodes.
I whish to filter thoses nodes and keep only the nodes whose nid is less than the nid of the node beeing edited.

the url of the node/edit form   is : /node/11541/edit?step=11538

the nid of the node being edited is : 11541

I wish the view to return only the nodes whose nid < 11541

I use [Views PHP](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_php)

Comment: this is for Drupal 7? Because I don't have test my code in Drupal 8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement the `hook_views_query_alter()` to alter your query and change the `=` operator by the `<` operator.

```
function YOUR_MODULE_NAME_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
  if($view->name == 'YOUR_VIEW_NAME') {
    /* Using the following line dmp($query)
     * (you need the devel module to use dpm) you will be able to search
     * where is condition to alter, you will see that in the 
     * $query->where[0]['conditions'][0]['field'] you will have:
     * node.nid = :node_nid
     * so your solution will be replace the 
     * = operator by the < operator
     * at this moment you can't do this from the Views UI
     */
    dpm($query);

    $query->where[0]['conditions'][0]['field'] = str_replace('=', '<', $query->where[0]['conditions'][0]['field']);
  }
}
```

I test the code and in my environment it works as I want it to.

Here is my view for if you want test the code (in this case the view name is articulos):

```
$view = new view();
$view->name = 'articulos';
$view->description = '';
$view->tag = 'default';
$view->base_table = 'node';
$view->human_name = 'articulos';
$view->core = 7;
$view->api_version = '3.0';
$view->disabled = FALSE; /* Edit this to true to make a default view disabled initially */

/* Display: Master */
$handler = $view->new_display('default', 'Master', 'default');
$handler->display->display_options['title'] = 'articulos';
$handler->display->display_options['use_more_always'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['access']['type'] = 'perm';
$handler->display->display_options['cache']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['query']['type'] = 'views_query';
$handler->display->display_options['exposed_form']['type'] = 'basic';
$handler->display->display_options['pager']['type'] = 'none';
$handler->display->display_options['style_plugin'] = 'default';
$handler->display->display_options['row_plugin'] = 'fields';
/* Field: Content: Title */
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['id'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['field'] = 'title';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['label'] = '';
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['word_boundary'] = FALSE;
$handler->display->display_options['fields']['title']['alter']['ellipsis'] = FALSE;
/* Sort criterion: Content: Post date */
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['id'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['field'] = 'created';
$handler->display->display_options['sorts']['created']['order'] = 'DESC';
/* Contextual filter: Content: Nid */
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['id'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['field'] = 'nid';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['default_argument_type'] = 'fixed';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['summary']['number_of_records'] = '0';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['summary']['format'] = 'default_summary';
$handler->display->display_options['arguments']['nid']['summary_options']['items_per_page'] = '25';
/* Filter criterion: Content: Published */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['id'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['field'] = 'status';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['value'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['group'] = 1;
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['status']['expose']['operator'] = FALSE;
/* Filter criterion: Content: Type */
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['id'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['table'] = 'node';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['field'] = 'type';
$handler->display->display_options['filters']['type']['value'] = array(
  'article' => 'article',
);

/* Display: Page */
$handler = $view->new_display('page', 'Page', 'page');
$handler->display->display_options['path'] = 'articulos/%';
$translatables['articulos'] = array(
  t('Master'),
  t('articulos'),
  t('more'),
  t('Apply'),
  t('Reset'),
  t('Sort by'),
  t('Asc'),
  t('Desc'),
  t('All'),
  t('Page'),
);
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian. It works great for one view in ma page, but not for the second view (see my code in my edited question), can my function handle 2 views with same query variable ?

Comment: Bienvenue dans le monde +5K ... PS: "... and it works" sounds a bit strange/bizarre. I understand you use it as a kind of quality assurance label (which is fine), but maybe you should use a phrasing like "in my environment it works as I want it to" ...

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens merci, ;-)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a contextual filter for your view:

- If you are using a page display, you will be able to retrieve the nid from the URL.
- If you are using a block display, you will need to do it a bit differently. See [Contextual filter with a block view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27818/contextual-filter-with-a-block-view)

Comment: Thanks for helping.

I use a page display and a contextual filter for another parameter : 

[view:metier=page_1=1]

If I'd wish to filter on "nid=   "  I know that I could use a contextual filter, 

but how to use a contextual filter in order to filter nid " is less than " ?

Comment: Sorry I read you to fast. you say for a page display I could retrieve nid from URL. But I don't see how to do it.