# Contextual filter using taxonomy alias

Tags: taxonomy-terms, 8, views

I have a list of nodes that I want to attach as a block to another node using a contextual filter. Depending on the URL alias I want a specific node to be attached to it. The problem is that I want the contextual filter to be based on a taxonomy alias as oppose to a taxonomy ID.

I looked at this solution: [Contextual filter with a block view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27818/contextual-filter-with-a-block-view) and this one: [Views contextual filters taxonomy name](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/9332/drupal-7-views-contextual-filters-taxonomy-name)  and I'm close however the second solution has an option that I can't find on my version. It reference a `Filter Value Type` option which would allow me to `Term name converted to Term ID`. This is exactly what I need, however I can't find this option.

I followed the instruction step-by-step; I tried creating different View and display versions, different items as my Contextual filter but nothing works.

These links are from 2011 and 2012, respectively. I'm using Drupal 8, so I'm wondering if this option has been removed or replaced with some other way to accomplish this task. Either way, I'd appreciate it any help.

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work by adding a relationship to a taxonomy field that exposed the taxonomy name. Then on the Contextual Filter I followed what the links said in regard to `Specify validation criteria`. But since I still can't find the `Filter Value Type` option, I just set the Case option to `Capitalize each word` and in the More section I checked the `Transform spaces to dashes in URL` option.

This allowed the value in the URL (which was a URL alias) to match my Taxonomy term field.

I don't know if there's an easier way to accomplish this and I'd still like to know why I couldn't find the `Filter Value Type` option, but at least it's working.