# Block View context filter does not appear in block configuration in layout editor

Tags: views

I am building a site in Drupal 10. I have created a View Block for displaying team members. Team Members have a field that is a taxonomy term (for what team they belong to), and a related context filter. The filter works in the "Preview" section of the View editor, properly displaying only team members in the specified team (by taxonomy term ID).

If I make a Basic Page and try to add the Team Member Block, the only configuration options available are # of results and "Display Title." I do not see any way to specify the context filter value. I have tried various configurations of the "specify validation criteria" menu. Selecting the "Content" validator only adds a dropdown box containing "None" and "Content" to the block configuration. Selecting "Taxonomy Term," "Taxonomy Term Name," or "Taxonomy Vocabulary" has no effect.

How can I configure the block such that I can specify the context filter value when adding it to the page? Because I am hoping to add this block to the same page multiple times using different filter values, there is no url parameter available for the filter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Contextual filter with a block view](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27818/contextual-filter-with-a-block-view)

Comment: This is a more recent issue https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2886116 where people have mixed results with your approach. You could try [#20](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/2886116#comment-13839366) using a contrib module to reference Views in a block type field that allows you to provide arguments.

Comment: @cilefen unfortunately, there is no URL parameter at play here because I want to include this block in my page multiple times, but with different context filters. I will update the question!

Comment: @4uk4 thanks, "Views Reference Field" looks interesting and might work out. I am limited by our platform on which contrib modules I'm allowed to install. I am thinking about just creating multiple block views with Fixed default filter values and adding the precise block view I want in each location.