# How do views Contextual Filters behave with Pathauto?

Tags: views, path-aliases

I have Pathauto installed, so URLs to nodes are not like `node/3`. My question is that if I write a View with a contextual filter for looking for `node/3`, will it work?

Note: This contextual filter is in a block. See [this question](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/13594/how-do-i-get-a-block-to-use-a-url-to-configure-a-contextual-filter).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would get the node id(nid) as argument. Internally the system gets its data from the unaliased url, not the browser url created with path_auto.

Answer (score 1):

pathauto only generates aliases. the nid stays the same. so contextual filters based on nid no problem.

Comment: I am talking about getting the nid out of the url, not doing a contextual filter based on the nid.