# View with same URL as node using Pathauto

Tags: views, nodes

I have a view with the URL of `/characters` and nodes with URL's in the form of `/characters/12/title-of-character`. When I visit the main view URL everything works, and all nodes are listed. When I visit the specific node URL however, I'm  shown the default frontpage.

I have no idea what's going on here and I'm breaking my head over this issue. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do views Contextual Filters behave with Pathauto?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45262/how-do-views-contextual-filters-behave-with-pathauto)

Comment: Sorry I meant this one : [Drupal 7 Contextual Filter on URL Alias](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60389/drupal-7-contextual-filter-on-url-alias)

Comment: I create views like the one you describe all of the time and that just doesn't happen. Can you export your view and post it in the OP? Also - don't think it's a dupe of [Drupal 7 Contextual Filter on URL Alias](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/60389/drupal-7-contextual-filter-on-url-alias) since contextual filters aren't even mentioned.